# Do Android build tools require to download Gradle for every new project?

Tags: android, linux, gradle, command-line

I have a couple of Android project samples I am going to build via the commandline using `./gradlew build` on Linux. Whenever I enter this command a message says "Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip". I think I already have the latest gradle under my Android Studio installation path. Why does this have to download gradle every time? Can I specify gradle as an environment variable e.g. GRADLE_HOME so that all projects can use it?

Answer (score 1):

What you have in your Android Studio installation path is not significant when using the Gradle Wrapper (`gradlew`). It downloads the exact version of Gradle that the current build is designed for and tested with if no other build downloaded it already. The downloaded distributions are stored under `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/`. So as long as you don't delete that folder and you have multiple builds that use the same gradle distribution in the wrapper configuration, that distribution will only be downloaded by the first build you execute. The others will use the already present distribution.